# Reading excel file in c++ dynamically

Tags: c++, excel

I have one windows application written in C++. This program should read data dynamically from an Excel file. The data of  this Excel File  is dynamically changed by another program with out being saved. I want to know if is there way I read this date during their change from my c++ code in visual studio?

The process should go like this:

1. c++ program read data form column 1 and row 1 in 6:10:20 pm and value of this cell is 60 and is right
2. the another program change the value of column1 and row 1 to 30 at 6:12:40
3. the c++ program read data of column1 and row 1 in 6:15:00 but the data is read yet is 60 and not read 30

I want my c++ application read 30 (the last value of that cell)

Comment: That's not possible unless the file was saved, only one process can open the excel file at a time.

Comment: ok, thanks I saw some things like DDE (Dynamic Data Exchange) what is this DLLs , it is not related to this topic?

Comment: IIRC this stuff was meant to present database connection based data in Excel.

Comment: You can create a Excel DLL otherwise known as a Excel Addin.  That Addin can do whatever you want it to, including reading from a specific cell.